# javascript check if number is between two numbers from object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to write a method that accepts a number, like 120 for example, how can i check 120 against the following object to where I can return the key "section1" of the object since 120 is between 100 and 200.  another example 267 would return "section2".

```
var obj = {
  'section1': 100,
  'section2': 200,
  'section3': 300
}
```

Lodash i s availabele to me if it helps.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```js
var obj = {
    'section1': 100,
    'section2': 200,
    'section3': 300
}

var BreakException = {};
function GetSection(number) {
    var lastKey = "not match";
    try {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            if (obj[key] > number) {
                //console.log(lastKey);
               // return lastKey;
                throw BreakException;
            }
            else {
                lastKey = key;
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e == BreakException) return lastKey;;
    }
    return "not match";
}

console.log(GetSection(120));
console.log(GetSection(267));
console.log(GetSection(10));
console.log(GetSection(500));
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, howerver, its not the way I envisioned it.  I'd rather return the section instantly rather than throwing a custom error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findKey function. First determine sectionValue and based on value, get key using findKey function.

```
var obj = {
  'section1': 100,
  'section2': 200,
  'section3': 300
}
var sectionValue;
if (test_number < 200)
    sectionValue = 100;
else if  (test_number < 300)   
    sectionValue = 200;
else  //have default else here
    sectionValue = 300
}

var key1 = _.findKey(obj,  sectionValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 120;
var array = [100, 200, 300];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(value >= array[i]){
        if(value < array[i+1]){
            console.log('Found it between ' + array[i] + ' and ' + array[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result after running:

```
"Found it between 100 and 200"
```

I am giving you a simple answer since you are asking a simple question without rules, so, **understand this**:

1. You will not get an "array out of index" or "array out of bounds" error cause this is Javascript, but understand that this is made to work as long as you do not give a value greater than the maximum value of your array. You can fix and validate this easily.
2. This logic only works based on the scenario you provide where the array is ordered.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic that a used in a similar situation where I needed run a check on pricing based the requested quantity and the price rules for that quantity.

```
        price_rules.forEach((element, index, rules) => {
            if(index >= 0 && (index < rules.length-1)){
                next_item = rules[index+1];
            }
            if((qty >= element.min && qty <= next_item.min) || (qty >= element.min && !next_item)){
                updateDisplayedPrice(element.price);
            }
        })
```